# How to automount directory as C: in DOSBox and autorun defined application

Tags: automounting, emulators

I know how to install DOSBox but run it always with a defined configuration?

- install `dosbox`
- automount a folder, let's say `/home/user/dos/c`
- run a defined application, let's say `boovie.exe` in boovie directory

Additionaly, for the purpose of each application I prefer a separate config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your favorite terminal and stay as normal user. And proceed as follows:

1. Install `dosbox` on Ubuntu/Debian-like systems with:

   `sudo apt-get install dosbox`
2. This will create the directory `dos` and inside it another directory `c` in your home folder:

   `mkdir -p ~/dos/c`
3. Now we need to export DOSBox' config file: We open DOSBox and type inside it:

   `config -writeconf /home/user/dos/boovie.conf`
   Of course, change `user` to your actual username. You cannot type `~/dosbox.conf` here. Change `boovie` to your actual DOS application name.
4. Open `/home/user/dos/boovie.conf` with your favorite text editor and scroll down to `[autoexec]` section, where you put these quite self-explanatory commands:

   ```
   mount c /home/user/dos/c
   c:
   cd boovie
   boovie
   ```

Which will automount `/home/user/dos/c` directory after DOSBox start-up. And it will go to `c:\boovie` and launch the `boovie.exe` application.

5. Lastly put `dosbox -conf /home/user/dos/boovie.conf` into your launcher. This way you may configure all your DOSBox applications separately.